# Why are blue/red options not showing?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Currently at tuchanka talking to mordin but the paragon or renegade options are not showing. Any help please?

Comment: can you give use a screenshot of your renegade/paragon bar?

Comment: I saw what happened now. Eve is efing alive that is why I can't persuade mordin to sabotage the cure. better do it in my next playthrough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might refer to the final scene, when it's question about conving I'm not to cure the Genophage. There is some situations were you won't be able to convince him using Paragon or Renegade speach.

> For instance if Wrex or Eve is alive, there is no way you'll convince him to sabotage the cure.

Comment: oh i see! eve is efing alive! how can i kill her? man, its hard for me to shoot mordin at the back just to stop curing the genophage! damn...

Comment: In fact Eve death is determined by your choice regarding mealon data in Mass effect 2 Mordin Loyalty Misson

Comment: @shepshep unfortunately this is entirely based on previous game's events, you can't save Mordin due to your history. You can only kill him or let him fix the genophage cure, dying in the process.

Comment: @shepshep aye, first time I did it, I shot mordin but regretted it while he was dragging himself to the console, spitting green blood the entire way.  Made my renegade shep feel bad so I reloaded.  :(  It was one of the few paragon things I did with that renegade playthrough

Answer (score 0):

If your Renegade/Paragon options are not showing more then likely you do not have enough Renegade/Paragon points to select these options. Although if i recall properly (correct me if im wrong) these Renegade/Paragon options should still show up if you do not have enough points in Renegade/Paragon, they will just be greyed out and not selectable.

Comment: nothing shows at all. maybe something is interfering with it